# Apache location directive exception

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I am trying to authenticate users for all URLs except for a regular expression:

`https://www.example.com/****anything****` should request authentication
`https://www.example.com/exams/****anything****` should NOT request authentication

This is my config today but it is not working:

```
<LocationMatch "^/exams">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</LocationMatch>

<Location "/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "PLEASE,AUTHENTICATE"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap-employees
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

It asks authentication for every URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this if you have `mod_authz_host` and `mod_rewrite`.  Basically set an environment variable if the URL matches /exams and look for that and if it's set allow access.  See the example below.  In this example you would not have the additional `<Location>` tag.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/exams.*" accessgranted=1

<Location "/">
    Order deny,allow
    Satisfy any
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=accessgranted
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "PLEASE,AUTHENTICATE"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap-employees
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow

Comment: Thanks for replying but it didn't work. Now it isn't asking for authentication for any URL

Comment: @brgsousa Just to confirm - you removed `Allow from all` from the `<Location "/">` tag right?

Comment: yep! I did! I copied exactly how you typed.

Comment: @brgsousa Ah, maybe `mod_rewrite` isn't firing early enough in the request.  Try using `SetEnvIf` instead.  I've updated the example.

Comment: yeeeeeaahhh! Now it worked!!